# Access fields of a foreign key of a form in a template

Tags: django

I am having trouble displaying the value of a field in a form in a template. The value should be available to the template, but it does not appear to be.

Here is the situation:

models.py:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class Pool(models.Model):
    ...
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Member, through='MemberPoolDates')

class MemberPoolDates(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    pool = models.ForeignKey(Pool)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
    pool = Pool.objects.get(id=pool_id)
    MemberFormSet = modelformset_factory(MemberPoolDates, form=MemberForm)
    memberformset = MemberFormSet(queryset=MemberPoolDates.objects.filter(
                                                                      pool=pool))
```

template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ poolform }}
</table>
<h2>Pool entries:</h2>
{{ memberformset.management_form }}
{% for memberform in memberformset %}
    {{ memberform.id }}
    {{ memberform.member }} 
    {{ memberform.member.name }}
    {{ memberform.member.description }}
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save pool"/>
</form>
```

In the template `{{ memberform.member }}` correctly displays a drop-down, but `{{ memberform.member.description }}` displays nothing and `{{ memberform.member.name }}` displays "member" instead of the value of member.name as text (what I wanted).

How can I access the fields of member in the template? More specifically, how can I display the value of member.name and member.description in my template through memberform?

Comment: Your code and description seem inconsistent, can this be ? You are talking about {{ memberform.name}} while in your code you are trying to print {{ memberform.member.name}}. The first one seems the more correct one to me.

Comment: @Jonas: corrected now - but the latter should be the correct one, because I want the name & description of the member (which is the foreign key) in the memberformset.

Comment: I think memberform will be a form based on your Member model. So to accesss the name attribute you'll need to {{ memberform.name}}

Comment: memberform is one form out of the memberformset (see code snipped above). That memberformset is based on the Model MemberPoolDates which has no name field, so {{ memberform.name }} is not valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try this in your template (accessing the modelinstance of the form):

```
{{ memberformset.management_form }}
{% for form in memberformset %}
    {{ form.instance.member.name }}
    {{ form.instance.member.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

This should output the desired fields as plain text.

Comment: Excellent, this works! (I just wonder how and where this is documented...)

Comment: As far as I know this is not documented, but may the source be with you ;)

Comment: Amazing works like a charm.Its a shame that it is not documented anywhere.

Comment: This works very well! Just went through the docs about 5 times looking for this. I found this useful with custom widgets or hidden inputs with foreign key ID's, where I still wanted to render some related attributes. This approach preserves the display when form validation fails, without having to tamper with the data.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for it for 2 hours now. 10 years old, still working. Nice!